# Xfwm4 settings "Maximize window" hotkey is not persistent across reboots

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfwm4

Whenever I change the "Maximize window" hotkey in Xfwm4 ( via Settings -> Keyboard), I can use that hotkey to maximize my windows, *until* I restart my computer.

The next time I go to the settings manager, the hotkey will still read "<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>", but pressing those keys won't work, unless I set it again. Needless to say: this is annoying.

If I'm missing any useful information, tell me what to look for and I'll do my best to find it.

```
OS: Xubuntu 14.04 trusty 
WM: Xfwm4
```